# Configuration of a specific topic. Kafkacat

Tags: apache-kafka, kcat

I have a topic "topic-one" and I want to know if it has "log.cleanup.policy = compact" configured or not.

Is it possible with kafkacat, extract the properties and / or configuration of a specific topic?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

kafkacat does not yet support the Topic Admin API (which allows you to alter and view cluster configs).
Suggest you use `kafka-configs.sh` from the Apache Kafka distribution in the meantine.